# DBeaver - ssh peer shut down incorrectly

Tags: presto, dbeaver, trino

I am using DBeaver as a SQL front-end to MySQL, as well as Presto / Trino
My back-end component are running in docker-compose on a Mac laptop.
Whenever I attempt to connect to Presto / Trino I get this error:

```
SQL Error: Error executing query: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
  Error executing query: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
  Error executing query: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
    javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
      Remote host terminated the handshake
      Remote host terminated the handshake
        SSL peer shut down incorrectly
        SSL peer shut down incorrectly
```

What should I change in order to be able to connect DBeaver to Presto / Trino running under Docker?

Answer (score 0):

Above error would be a problem with the SSL handshake between DBeaver and Presto.
Could you please check the below documentation enable the SSL.

https://prestodb.io/docs/current/security/internal-communication.html